# Python & Google Sheets: What's the best method to read/write?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm starting a project at work, and am attempting to read/manipulate Google Sheets. I have successfully followed the [Google Sheets API v4 Quickstart Guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python), and am able to read the sheet they have included in step 3.

However, when I try to change the `spreadsheetId` to a separate sheet and the scope to the Google Drive one, it errors out with the following:

```
  File "quickstart.py", line 81, in <module>
    main()
  File "quickstart.py", line 58, in main
    credentials = get_credentials()
  File "quickstart.py", line 40, in get_credentials
    credentials = store.get()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 407, in get
    return self.locked_get()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\file.py", line 54, in locked_get
    credentials = client.Credentials.new_from_json(content)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 302, in new_from_json
    module_name = data['_module']
KeyError: '_module'
```

I found the gspread library, and imported it. I can successfully change the client.open_by_key() value to my spreadsheet, and can set the range with the Google Drive Feeds scope. However, it looks like there has to be a full reference for the range ('A2:E50'), and it can't read something like ('A2:E') like the code from Google can.

I think the Sheets API v4 should contain all of the functions that I need to read/manipulate the sheet. However, I'd like to also include the Google Drive one so that I could also make Google Docs based off of the same data.

Does anyone have any information on why gspread would need to be used over the regular Sheets/Google Drive API? What would need to be changed in the Google code example to allow the Google Drive API instead?

Any help or information you all could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure whether I could understand your question. Do you want to use both Sheets API and Drive API using google-api-python-client? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @tanaike, sorry for not being clear. My understanding of the Sheets API is that it's only for manipulating Sheets. I'd like to eventually be able to process Google Docs with the data within the Google Sheet. That's why I was assuming I would need to use the Drive API. Is that not correct?

Comment: Can I ask you about the process of Google Docs? Google Docs means Google Document? Or it means all of spreadsheet, document, slide and so on? I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @tanaike I'm referring to the actual product. Google Docs = Google Document.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You want to read/write the Google Document using the data of Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @tanaike, that is correct. The documentation from Google has read only access.

Comment: Do you want to read data from Google Document? If my understanding is correct, there are no APIs for managing Google Document. So how about using Google Apps Script between Python and Google Document as a workaround?

Comment: Can you call an Apps Script from within the Google Sheets API? If so, that would work.

Comment: Google Apps Script cannot be called by Sheets API. Sheets API is used for operating Spreadsheet. My proposal is that it calls Google Apps Script using Execution API and Web Apps. If the process you want is simple, Web Apps may be suitable for your situation. As a flow, 1. Retrieve data from Spreadsheet using Sheets API. 2. Send a request for the process you need using the retrieved data. 3. Process the request using Google Apps Script.

Comment: I'm sorry... I don't understand what you're explaining. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience. In order to understand what you want to do, can I ask you about the detail flow of it? I would like to propose the sample flow using GAS for your information.

Comment: Our business case is to read values from a Google Sheet, do some manipulation, post to MSSQL server. Then, on the flip side, read from MSSQL server, do some manipulation, post results  back to Google Sheets.

Comment: Where is Google Document used?

Comment: My company is G Suite, so everything is hosted in my corporate Google Drive.

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor English skill. You said ``that is correct`` for my question of ``You want to read/write the Google Document using the data of Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?``. But you said ``Our business case is to read values from a Google Sheet, do some manipulation, post to MSSQL server. Then, on the flip side, read from MSSQL server, do some manipulation, post results back to Google Sheets.`` Because I was confused by this, I asked ``Where is Google Document used?``.